# Button Not Being Added to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working on a custom keyboard that contains a UICollectionView using Swift.  The collection view is iterating through an array of images (this works great) and creates the appropriate number of cells based on the array count.

I am trying to add a button to the cell, and while the cell is created the button is not getting added. Any thoughts or help is much appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(turkeyReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

    let shareButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(123, 123, 40, 40))
    shareButton.setTitle("Button", forState: .Normal)
    shareButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    shareButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    cell.addSubview(shareButton)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Are you sure of you button's frame ? Furthermore, you should add shareButton to cell.contentView

Comment: I have tried using it with contentView to the same result. 

Forgive my ignorance, I'm still a fairy new iOS developer, how can I check my button's frame?

Comment: What I meant by checking button's frame, is that you set it to be within your cell. For your button to be fully visible with your current setup, your collectionView cell must have a width and height >= 123+40, otherwise it'll be outside the visible part of your cell

Comment: Make sense. I changed the frame dimensions and now it's working.